# Is there a way to define a full block of code as a variable as a stand in for a goto function on python?

Tags: python, variables, goto

This is what I have.
At three points (End of Mercy, Flee, and Else) I want it to loop back to the Act menu.
I'm not sure how to do this however. I'm very new to coding so I would really appreciate examples.

````
ATK=5
DEF=2
MHP=40
MATK=5

print("A Monster approaches you!")
print("Fight, Mercy, Flee")

a=input("Act:")
if a == "Fight":
    MNHP=MHP-ATK
    MHP=MNHP
    print("You hit the enemy for ", ATK, " damage!")
    print("Enemy HP remaining: ", MHP)
elif a == "Mercy":
    print("You tried to spare the enemy...")
    if(MHP<15):
        print("You won!")
        print("You gained 0 EXP and 5 G")
    else:
        NHP=HP-MATK
        HP=NHP
        print("But the Monster wasn't weakened enough.")
        print("You lost ", MATK, "HP. HP remaining: ", HP)
elif a == "Flee":
    print("You tried to flee... But the overworld is missing.")
else:
    print("That's not an option.")```
````

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Because your problem is stated like it's only needs a simple loop, but I'd suspect it's not as easy since you've posted it in here. What exactly are you doing and what do you want to loop over?

Comment: Wrap it in a `while` loop.

Comment: As I said I'm very new to code... I have no idea how to use a loop-

Comment: I'm confused with the statement **goto function on python**

Comment: Also, I intend to add other menus and interactions later, so I'm not sure if a loop would work.

Comment: "I'm confused with the statement goto function on python." Yeah, there isn't one. That's what I mean by a stand in.

Comment: If you want it to "loop" back, then use an actual looping construct, like `while` or `for`. If you "have no idea how to use a loop", then *Stack Overflow is not the right place to get help* - you should follow along with a Python tutorial instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better to use some functions, like this one:

```
def battle(ATK=5, DEF=2, MHP=40, MATK=5, HP=20):
    print("A Monster approaches you!")
    print("Fight, Mercy, Flee")

    action = input("Act: ")
    if action == 'leave':
        # leave the dungeon
        return False

    if action == "Fight":
        MHP -= ATK
        print("You hit the enemy for ", ATK, " damage!")
        print("Enemy HP remaining: ", MHP)
    elif action == "Mercy":
        print("You tried to spare the enemy...")
        if MHP < 15:
            print("You won!")
            print("You gained 0 EXP and 5 G")
        else:
            HP -= MATK
            print("But the Monster wasn't weakened enough.")
            print("You lost ", MATK, "HP. HP remaining: ", HP)
    elif action == "Flee":
        print("You tried to flee... But the overworld is missing.")
    else:
        print("That's not an option.")
    # return True to keep fighting
    return True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fight = True
    while fight:
        fight = battle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help and support.
With a little tweaking I believe I have solved my problem.
It's not the prettiest bit of code, but it gets the job done.

```
HP=20
ATK=5
DEF=2
MHP=40
MATK=5

print("A Monster approaches you!")

while HP>0:
    print(" ")
    print("Fight, Mercy, Flee, Heal")
    
    a=input("Act:")
    if a == "Fight":
        MNHP=MHP-ATK
        MHP=MNHP
        if(MHP<=0):
            print(" ")
            print("You won!")
            print("You gained 7EXP and 2G")
            break
        else:
            print(" ")
            print("You hit the enemy for ", ATK, " damage!")
            print("Enemy HP remaining: ", MHP)
            print(" ")
            NHP=HP-MATK
            HP=NHP
            print("You lost ", MATK, "HP. HP remaining: ", HP)
    elif a == "Mercy":
        print(" ")
        print("You tried to spare the enemy...")
        if(MHP<15):
            print("You won!")
            print("You gained 0 EXP and 5 G")
            break
        else:
            print(" ")
            NHP=HP-MATK
            HP=NHP
            print("But the Monster wasn't weakened enough.")
            print("You lost ", MATK, "HP. HP remaining: ", HP)
    elif a == "Flee":
        NHP=HP-MATK
        HP=NHP
        print(" ")
        print("You tried to flee... But the overworld is missing.")
        print("You lost ", MATK, "HP. HP remaining: ", HP)
    elif a == "Heal":
        NHP=HP+3
        HP=NHP
        print(" ")
        print("You healed 3 HP.")
        print("HP:", HP)
    else:
        print(" ")
        print("That's not an option.")
```